# How to retrieve individual value from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare two values, and am getting `Value Error: Series lengths must match to compare`. Below is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np

Input = pd.read_csv('C:/PyTemp/IN.csv')
Template = pd.read_csv('C:/PyTemp/Length.csv')

Start = pd.merge(Template, Input, on = 'AGE', how = 'left')

InitialAge = Input['AGE']

loopcount = 105
i = 1
while i < loopcount:
    Start.ix[Start.AGE > InitialAge, 'SI'] = Start['SI'].shift()
    i += 1

Start.to_csv('C:/PyTemp/' + 'Output' + '.csv', header = True)
```

When I subsitute:

```
while i < loopcount:
    Start.ix[Start.AGE > 16, 'SI'] = Start['SI'].shift()
    i += 1
```

The code works properly.

```
print(InitialAge)
print(Start.AGE)
```

Yields

```
0    16
Name: AGE, dtype: int64

0    1
0    2
---
0    105
Name: AGE, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `InitialAge` is a `pandas.Series`, not an `integer`, which is what you are probably looking for.

Try instead:

```
InitialAge = Input.get_value(0, 'AGE')
```

Comment: Your answer was ideal. Thanks.